# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so'

Tags: php, redis, centos

I try to upgrade php to 8.0.1 when I finish install php and I find like that. How can I do ?

[root@localhost /]# php -v

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so'
> (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so
> (/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor),
> /usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so.so
> (/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so.so: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2021 13:54:54) ( NTS gcc x86_64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans

os: Centos 7

Comment: First question, is `redis.so` there to be loaded in any of the places PHP is looking? Second Question: If not is it somewhere else?

Comment: You are upgading to PHP8.0.1 from ___What version?___

Comment: Is the redis server installed and running?

Comment: 3. redis server is running
"[root@localhost /]# sudo systemctl status redis
● redis.service - redis-server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d
           └─limit.conf
   Active: active (running) since"

Comment: 2.upgrading to php 8.0.1 from 7.1.0.

Comment: So are you checking 1. now. Because I dont think redis.so is automatically provided

Answer (score 0):

I remove redis from centos 7.I'm not sure 100% correct but I didn't see "PHP Warning:".

> [root@localhost ~]# sudo yum remove redisp
>
> [root@localhost local]# rm -R redis

> [root@localhost local]# cd /usr/lib64/php/modules

> [root@localhost modules]# rm redis.so

> [root@localhost modules]# cd /etc/php.d/
>
> [root@localhost php.d]# rm redis.ini"

> [root@localhost php.d]# php -v PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2021
> 13:54:54) ( NTS gcc x86_64 ) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine
> v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans

Answer (score 0):

You possibly got this [issue](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1589).

Redis extension must be loaded **after** json extension.

Look back to the answer you left above, the PHP warning was gone after you removed `/etc/php.d/redis.ini`, the point is that PHP configuration files are usually loaded in **alphanumeric order**. Therefore, in the scenario you described, `redis.ini` would be loaded before `20-json.ini` which causes the issue [@remicollet](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1589#issuecomment-508412700) mentioned.

So what I recommend you do is to rename `redis.ini` to `50-redis.ini` and restart PHP-related services.